# Word 2010 / 2013 VBA - set selection to be that of a named range

Tags: vba, ms-word, range, selection

I've searched web without results for how to do a simple task.
Make the selection that of a named range. I keep getting a duplication of the text in the named range, not a selection. Code with comments:

```
Sub SetSelectionFromRange()
' Goal: Set current selection to be that of a named range
' text of doc is "One Two" and at start the insertion bar is between "w" and "o"
    Dim myRange4 As Range
    Set myRange4 = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=0, End:=3)
    Selection.Range = myRange4.Duplicate        
' result expected is "One" selected and no change in text
' result actual is "One TwOneo" and insertion bar left after "w" (no selection)`
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
Selection.Range = myRange4.Duplicate
```

Try:

```
 myRange4.Select
```

Comment: Perfect. Too simple and obvious for me to see. Much thanks Zuma